# Stripe iOS SDK - Format for State and Country While Creating Token

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments

I'm wondering what format for state and country I should be passing in the STPCardParams while creating a token in Stripe with the iOS SDK.

In my code, I have the following:

```
        STPCardParams *card = [[STPCardParams alloc] init];
        card.number = self.paymentView.cardParams.number;

        card.expMonth = self.paymentView.cardParams.expMonth;
        card.expYear = self.paymentView.cardParams.expYear;
        card.cvc = self.paymentView.cardParams.cvc;
        card.addressZip = self.zipField.text;
        card.addressLine1 = self.addressField.text;
        card.addressCity = self.cityField.text;
        card.addressCountry = self.countryField.text;
        card.addressState = self.stateField.text;

        [[STPAPIClient sharedClient] createTokenWithCard:card completion:^(STPToken *token, NSError *error) { ......
```

My question is, should I be formatting the user's input for state and country.

For example, should it be:

"California, United States of America" or "CA, US"

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly permissive about it, I'd suggest peering into the Tests within the iOS SDK.

Specifically, https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/Tests/Tests/STPCardTest.m#L45

And https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/Tests/Tests/STPCardFunctionalTest.m#L19

My personal choice might be to format it as "CA, US" (Two letter ISO code is how Stripe generally stores countries).

https://stripe.com/docs/api#card_object-country